# While loop for radioactive decay. ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, numpy, physics

```
def calculateEuler(nuclei_A, nuclei_B, tau_A, tau_B, time, dt, n):
    i = 0
    while i < n-1:
        nuclei_A[i+1] = nuclei_A[i] - (nuclei_A[i]/tau_A)*dt
        nuclei_B[i+1] = nuclei_B[i] + (nuclei_A[i]/tau_A)*dt - (nuclei_B[i]/tau_B)*dt
        time[i+1] = time[i] + dt
        i = i+1
    return nuclei_A, nuclei_B, time
```

I am trying to write a function that approximates the number of nuclei (A and B) as they undergo radioactive decay. The initial number of nuclei, nuclei_A[0] and nuclei_B[0] have already been assigned in a previous function.

I am getting two errors for the line determining nuclei_B.:

```
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars.

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I am having trouble understanding what these errors mean and what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Please provide enough information for someone to re-create the problem.

Comment: In particular, please show how you call this function and how its arguments are created.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you could get rid of those `i = 0`, `i = i + 1`, etc if you simply used a for loop. `for i in range(len(nuclei_A)-1):`.

Comment: I don't know what reasonable values are for tau, dt, or n, but if I initialize nuclei_A, nuclei_B, and time as numpy arrays with some starting value, your function runs without error.

Comment: @Will.Evo I would bet that they used a list for `dt`.

Answer (score 0):

The following runs without error and each of the species reach zero in the time allotted. I didn't make any changes to your function. If you find that initializing with different values breaks this code, you might reformat your question with this code example and those values.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def calculateEuler(nuclei_A, nuclei_B, tau_A, tau_B, time, dt, n):
    i = 0
    while i < n-1:
        nuclei_A[i+1] = nuclei_A[i] - (nuclei_A[i]/tau_A)*dt
        nuclei_B[i+1] = nuclei_B[i] + (nuclei_A[i]/tau_A)*dt - (nuclei_B[i]/tau_B)*dt
        time[i+1] = time[i] + dt
        i = i+1
    return nuclei_A, nuclei_B, time

n = 100
A = np.zeros((n))
B = np.zeros((n))
A[0] = 10000
B[0] = 10000
tA = 1.6
tB = 2
time = np.zeros((n))
dt = .5

rA, rB, rT = calculateEuler(A, B, tA, tB, time, dt, n)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(rT, rA)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(rT, rB)
```

I had a little fun with this and was able to speed up the code substantially for no other reason than it was easy. The function written above runs in ~ 2.91 ms on average for a 1000 time step simulation. The function below runs in ~0.009 ms on average for the same length time array.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numba import njit

@njit(nogil=True, cache=True)
def calculateEuler(nuclei_A, nuclei_B, tau_A, tau_B, dt):

    for idx in range(nuclei_A.size):
        if idx == nuclei_A.size - 1 : break
        nuclei_A[idx+1] = nuclei_A[idx] - (nuclei_A[idx]/tau_A)*dt
        nuclei_B[idx+1] = nuclei_B[idx] + (nuclei_A[idx]/tau_A)*dt - (nuclei_B[idx]/tau_B)*dt
    return nuclei_A, nuclei_B

n = 1000
A = np.zeros((n))
B = np.zeros((n))
A[0] = 1e7
B[0] = 1e7
tA = 1.6
tB = 2
dt = 0.5
time = np.arange(0, n*dt, dt)

rA, rB = calculateEuler(A, B, tA, tB, dt)
```